# Scanner and while loop addition

Tags: java

I just posted yesterday but I am back with another question, I know the answer to this problem but I'm stuck on how they got it.

```
import java.util.*;
public class test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "12 13 14 15 18 16 17 20 2";
    Scanner c = new Scanner(s);
    int sum = 0;
    while(c.nextInt()% 2 == 0)
        sum += c.nextInt();
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

The output is `44` but I keep getting `46` on my own. I may be doing it wrong since I am not too familiar on how `c.nextInt()` works.

I am thinking it goes:

```
12 % 2 = 0, so add 13
14 % 2 = 0, so add 15
18 % 2 = 0, so add 16
17 % 2 =/= 0, so skip
20 % 2 = 0, so add 2
for a total of = 46
```

am I missing something?

EDIT: Solved, forgot that loops don't just "skip". I'm dumb

Comment: What do you mean _skip_? A loop stops once its condition evaluates to `false`.

Comment: I was so focused on that 20 and 2 that I forgot about that.. You are my savior, I feel stupid now. Thank you! @Pillar

Answer (score 0):

Yes , here answer is 44. Here you are repeating while loop until ( number%2 == 0 ) became FALSE.
in your case :

you are adding 13 + 15 + 16 and the next number to check the while condition is 17

here ( 17%2 == 0 ) is FALSE so condition fails and is not entering into the loop .

here comes the total 44 ( 13 + 15 + 16 )

I hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a breakdown going through the loop each time:

- c.nextInt() gets 12, 12 % 2 == 0, so this condition is TRUE

  - sum = 0 and c.nextInt() = 13 so sum += 13 equals 13
- Second c.nextInt() gets 14, 14 % 2 == 0, so this condition is TRUE

  - sum = 13 and c.nextInt() = 15 so sum += 15 equals 28
- c.nextInt() gets 18, 18 % 2 == 0, so this condition is TRUE

  - sum = 0 and c.nextInt() = 16, so sum += 16 equals 44
- c.nextInt() gets 17, 17 % 2 == 1, so this condition is FALSE, the loop exits

Print 44

Answer (score 0):

Java while loop is used to execute statement(s) until a condition holds true.If the condition holds false , this while loop will be break out.So

17 % 2 != 0, this while loop will be break out.So sum=44.